# Disable detail dynamically on Delphi master/detail

Tags: delphi, master-detail, fastreport

I have two reports I'm redoing.
The first has basic info, and the second has the exact same thing plus some more information.

Both are made using FastReport and master/detail with TSqlQuery and TClientDataset.

The first has 3 details and the second has 5.

Is there a way to make only one report document and disable the details dynamically?

Obs: I can't load the TClientDataset and then hide the elements on the first report because the query takes a long time to run: about 30 seconds to load the first report and about 10 minutes for the second one.

Comment: Have you tris disabling the TDataSources which connect the Master to the Details?

Comment: @MartynA there is only one TDataSouce for all the 5 TSqlQuery, if I disable it all go down.

Comment: Unles I can make multiple TDataSource, dang, that may do it. Thanks

Comment: In case you are not aware, there is no restriction on the number of datasources that can connect to a Master dataset.

Comment: @MartynA happiness was short lived, it didn't work. It is automatically reactivated or is not the option that does the trick.

Comment: Well, you can always clear a TDataSource's DataSet property and reinstate it later ...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @MartynA for the help.

I manage to do it but it took more work than I think it should.

1. Clear the **DataSource** property on your TSqlQuery;
2. Clear the **DataSetField** property on your TClientDataSet (detail);
3. Remove the field used on **DataSetField** from your TClientDataSet (master);
4. And if you're using FastReport, the ClientDataSet must be active so you use the method **CreateDataSet**.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted - I rarely work with FastReports myself.